# line-height css and printing

Tags: html, printing, css

I'm making a small responsive website and I'm having a little problem.

While I was watching at a print-preview of my website, I noticed that the last line of my page was only printed half.

I know that the text block where this occurs has a "line-height:135%;" styling, to get a nice spacing between the lines when reading.

My printer mediaquerie doesn't overwrite this "line-height:135%;"-property, because I want to keep the nice line spacing when printed. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

I know I can fix this by setting the line-height, back to 100% in the print mediaquery, but I want to keep that spacing.
(Here is a picture of the problem:  http://s7.postimg.org/5bf8tfqor/theproblem.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

edit:
this is the css I use to style the article, nothing fancy as you can see.

```
article {
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: "Special Elite", cursive;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height:135%;
}
```

Comment: use @media print{ yourclass{line-height:100%;}} for only during print the line-height: 100% not 135%

Comment: but how can I keep the linspacing when printed out? Because that's what I want.

Comment: It's unlikely the the half printed line has has something to do with the line height. It's probably something else in your style sheet. Post an URL. BTW, Comic Sans? [Seriously?](http://www.comicsanscriminal.com/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is the line-height that is set to 135% because, when I set the line-height to 100% in the printer mediaquerie, that problem goes away. But the line spacing is also lost ofc. And font-family might still change :p

Comment: I am trying to say that use @media print and whatever style u want to put in your page while printing you can add. That style only reflects during print that page.

Comment: If you want to keep the spacing AND make it fit on one page, you probably need to adjust some other styles / parts of the design to fit the page...

Comment: Just because you see the problem when the line height is set to 135% doesn't mean that it causes the problem. Do you use any absolute positioning on your page? There is more that can cause this other than just the styles applied directly to the `article` element.

Comment: @RoToRa , a little bit offtopic but which font would you suggest for a modern/fresh cooking website?

Comment: have you tried using `em` for `line-height`?

Comment: em, didn't do the trick. I did use some absolute positioning in the header, but I'm setting the header to display:none and still the problem occurs.

Comment: I fixed the problem by setting the div that contains everything on my page to width:95% instead of width:100%. I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but it might be something with the absolute positioning. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are plenty of fonts here: http://www.google.com/fonts/ You'll need to post an URL without it's basically impossible to solve.

Comment: `width: 100%` is almost always wrong. Use `width: auto` (which is the default) instead.

Comment: you sir are my hero ! ;)

Comment: well the site is still under construction, but this is a screenshot of what i've already have: http://s17.postimg.org/vw3dvox1r/thepage.jpg , the font I have now is already from google fonts, but I'm not happy with it :p